# Decrypt EncryptSymmetric in Demandware (Commerce Cloud)

Tags: encryption, commerce-cloud

Hey is there a way to decrypt a encrypted message from Marketing Cloud in the Commerce Cloud (formerly Demandware)?

The function used in Marketing Cloud in encrypt is this:

```
EncryptSymmetric('secretMessage', 'AES', @null, 'secretnumber', @null, '0000000000000000', @null, '00000000000000000000000000000000')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commerce Cloud has the `dw.crypto` namespace which contains a `Cipher` class. You can use the `Cipher.encrypt` and `Cipher.decrypt` methods to achieve this. See: https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/scriptapi/html/api/class_dw_crypto_Cipher.html?cp=0_16_2_5_1